# SASS variable is not calculated before exporting to React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

src/components/data/_variables.module.scss

```
$carousel-width: 1000px;
$slides-amount: 4;
$carousel-width: min($carousel-width, ( calc(100vw - 100px) ));
$slide-width: calc($carousel-width/$slides-amount);
:export {
     slideWidth: $slide-width;
}
```

src/components/Carousel/Carousel.component.jsx

```
import vars from "../../data/_variables.module.scss"
/*... other imports ...*/

class Carousel extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.slideWidth = vars.slideWidth;
        this.state = { ...... // the rest of the code
```

Before i was using hard-coded variables for slideWidth, and it worked fine.

But when i tried to calculate them for better mobile styling support, i've noticed that while scss calculates everything correctly, somehow it passes not the result of calculations, but the whole equation as a string to React.

As a result i get `'calc(min(1000px, 100vw - 100px) / 4)'` string instead of required variable. At the same time i'm exporting $carousel-width to another scss file and it behaves correctly (changing the value according to initial value and screen witdth).

**TL;DR: How to force SCSS to calculate variables before exporting them?**

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://www.bluematador.com/blog/how-to-share-variables-between-js-and-sass

Comment: There is nothing in that tutorial that could help me. parseInt does not help to evaluate the expression since it skips all non-numerical values. Furthermore, you can't really evaluate `calc(min(1000px, 100vw - 100px) / 4)` in React since js does not know about css units.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should understand how sass works.

In some conditions Sass won't calculate variables until you write them in #{$var1 * $var2}

And for division you have to use 'sass:math' module.

And some values can't be calculated, like
100vh - 100px

You would get error. Because they are incompatible units.

Hope you understood.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the answer. I've actually rewritten the code to do all required calculation on JS side and it went fine.
Actually, i've noticed that it CAN calculate 100vh-100px, because i've noticed that in other scss file where i exported these variables they were calculated and applied to my component. (i. e. i had screen width of 1000px, and got carousel-width of 900px). I'll read about #{} approach and the sass module later. Thanks again!